# ASP.net set the Top and Left position of a Panel (Div) using server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am using Visual Studio Express 2010, C#

I have a div and need to set it's absolute position (Top, Left) in the server side code.  The position of the div is read in from a file on the server.  I can set the width and height (also read in from a file) but so far I have not been able to find away of setting the position.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Could you paste in some relevant code? Are you using some kind of framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify attributes in code using:

```
MyPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "position: [your_position]");
```

Kris

Answer (score 3):

You can also set it like this

```
YourDivID.Style["position"] = "absolute";
YourDivID.Style["top"] = "20px"; //--- replace with your value
YourDivID.Style["left"] = "20px"; //--- replace with your value
```

Good Luck!